# Как можно сделать вот такой элемент на CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

Не знаю как лучше оформить такое решение на css

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском по сайту, уже минимум 3 раза задавали этот вопрос с точно такой же рамкой.

Comment: <fieldset><legend></legend> </fieldset>

Comment: В защиту автора: что вбъешь в поиск?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы не сложная вёрстка

```css
.orient {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 6px solid gold;
  transform: translate(80px, 30px);
  position: relative;
}

.bottom {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
}

.bottom a {
  color: gold;
}

.top {
  width: 100px;
  height: 130px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="orient">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="">learn more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!